# Request.form.get() returns None

Tags: python, html, css, function, flask

I'm trying to build a budget tracker website using Python and Flask where you can keep track of how you spend your money. I've included a section where you select the type of spending, but when i try to retrieve the user selection  using Flask the `request.form.get()` returns `None`.

I also tried to store the selected variable in a session but it does not work and I tried the `request.form\["selected"\]` but it gives me a 400 error.

Anyone knows how I can fix this issues?

Here is my HTML:

```html
<form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <h3 class="h3">Your expenses</h3>
  <div class="top">
    <input type="number" class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" placeholder="$0.00" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
  </div>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Add Expense</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Category: </h1>
          <div>
            <select id="category-select" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
              <option id="selected" name="selected" selected>Select type</option>
              <option id="home" name="home" value="0">Home</option>
              <option id="loans" name="loans" value="1">Loans</option>
              <option id="entertainment" name="entertainment" value="2">Entertainment</option>
              <option id="transportation" name="transportation" value="3">Transportation</option>
              <option id="other" name="other" value="5">Other</option </div>
            </select>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="$0.00" aria-describedby="button-addon2" min="1">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" id="addBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Add money</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is my Python code below:

```py
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def index():
   
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("index.html")
    else:
        # Get data from user input

        user_id = session["user_id"]
        date = datetime.datetime.now()

        # Check user cash
        usr_cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", user_id)[0]["cash"]

        # Check expense amount
        amount = int(request.form.get("amount"))

        # Check if user has enough money for expense
        if usr_cash < amount:
            return apology("Not enough money for this expense! Try adding more income")

        # Update user cash after expense
        updt_cash = usr_cash - amount

        # Update database

        db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = ? WHERE id = ?", updt_cash, user_id)

        # Create transactions list
        selected = request.form.get("selected")
        
        if selected == "Home":
            db.execute("INSERT INTO category (home, user_id, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", amount, user_id, date)
        elif selected == "Loans":
            db.execute("INSERT INTO category (loans, user_id, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", amount, user_id, date)
        elif selected == "Entertainment":
            db.execute("INSERT INTO category (entertainment, user_id, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", amount, user_id, date)
        elif selected == "Transportation":
            db.execute("INSERT INTO category (transportation, user_id, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", amount, user_id, date)
        elif selected == "Other":
            db.execute("INSERT INTO category (other, user_id, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", amount, user_id, date)

        print(selected)

        return render_template("index.html")
```

Comment: I don't think it should matter, but there's no need to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` when you're not uploading a file.

Comment: Yes i deleted it and it still returns None :(

Comment: Does the Network tab of DevTools show that you're sending all the form parameters? What does `print(request.form)` show?

Comment: I just read in the Flask documentation that when using request.form[".."] if the parameter is None it will trigger an error 400. the print(request.form) shows exactly: None

Comment: `request.form` should never be `None`, it should be a dictionary, possibly empty.

Comment: So how is this possible? It literally prints None on my terminal Please I've been stuck on this for hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `select` is incorrect.

You only need `value` in your `options`. Get rid of `id` and `name`.

Also flask is looking for a name for your field.  Add one to this:

```
 <select id="category-select"
```